# Issues with Liferay 7.1 workspace imported from Github

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-ide

I have cloned my Liferay 7.1 workspace from my Github repository. When I try to get Assistance in Liferay IDE using Control+Space, I get error:

```
This compilation unit is not on the build path of a java project
```

This happens on the new module project created in the same workspace(that was cloned from Github).
But when I create/import module from my local workspace that was created by Liferay for first time, this issue is not there.

I feel like there is some extra workspace setting that I am not doing in my Github workspace. Like we had to create build.username.properties in the SDK folder for Liferay 6.2. Totally stuck and no solutions anywhere.

I tried fixing Project Build path and Project Facets but did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some differences between the workspace that I imported from Github and the one that Liferay was creating on my local. I opened both the workspaces in Beyond Compare. Following are the files that had major differences. I made them same and it started working after Gradle Refresh in Eclipse.

- `liferay-workspace/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
- `liferay-workspace/.project`
- `liferay-workspace/gradle.properties`
- `liferay-workspace/gradlew`
- `liferay-workspace/settings.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it in your own answer obviously solved it. My take on this is: The problem was most likely the `.project` file, because it contains all the configuration that eclipse requires, and the error message you post is an indicator that eclipse doesn't know what to do with these files.

The `.project` file can be regenerated from gradle settings, typically by choosing "gradle / refresh" (from memory, from the context menu of the project/workspace in Project Explorer), which will read the gradle settings and apply them to the eclipse world. This might happen automatically, but it might also need some manual push - next time you might want to try this, because just copying random files rarely is a good idea. You might end up pointing to other directories far outside of your workspace, and wonder why a local change is not picked up.